# Reset position of background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my Background.as I have the following code to make the background scroll:

```
package{

    //Defining the class
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Background extends MovieClip{

        function Background()
        {
            //Executes the enterFrame function
            addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);

        }

        function enterFrame(e:Event)
        {
            this.x -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The background is a Moveclip with AS Linkage set as `Background`. I was wondering how I could reset the background back to it's starting position within a function in my `Main.as`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the original position before any changes are applied, and refer to that:

```
public class Background extends MovieClip
{

    private var _startPosition:Point;


    public function Background()
    {
        _startPosition = new Point(x, y);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _enterFrame);
    }


    private function _enterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        x -= 1;
    }


    public function reset():void
    {
        x = _startPosition.x;
        y = _startPosition.y;
    }

}
```

Comment: So if this code is in my `Background.as`, how would I call the reset function in `Main.as`? I want it so that when the user replays the game, the background resets to the original position.